# error running selenium, chrome location and chrome driver issue

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I dont know what i am doing wrong. I checked the location of google chrome to be in the correct folder.
Also I put the chrome driver in the correct folder as well. What am I doing wrong?

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/Trader/Documents/chromedriver", options=options)
```

Error code:

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create a Chrome process.

Comment: Have you tried calling `webdriver.Chrome()` with your full path? i.e. `webdriver.Chrome("C://Users//Trader//Documents//chromedriver.exe", options=options)` I also don't think you need `binary_location` at all here.

Comment: Did U tried basic setup from chromedriver page ???